# WSO2 API Manager - migration from H2 to MySQL : one script is missing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In wso2am/repository/conf/datasources/*.xml, I can see 5 datasources :

```
    <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
    <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
    <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
    <name>WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>

    <name>WSO2_METRICS_DB</name>
```

But in wso2am/dbscripts, I can find only 4 scripts for 4 databases (no script for WSO2AM_STATS_DB).

Is WSO2AM_DB supposed to stay an H2 database in production ? or should it point to an existing database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create tables in `WSO2AM_STATS_DB` manually. Just creating a database is enough. Tables are automatically created by analytics scripts.

> Table creation of the statistics database is handled by the Analytics
>   scripts when you configure APIM Analytics, so you will create the
>   statistics database in this step but will not specify a source script.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+API+Manager+2.0.0

Comment: Ok, thanks. This information is missing in the non-cluster setup : https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Setting+up+MySQL